# migrate PostgreSQL to MySQL (wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, postgresql, plugins

So as you can read in the heading I have a question with databases

We want to show datas out of the PostgreSQL in our Wordpress Website

Is there any code or a Plugin (it should Work in Wordpress 4.3)
or is there a program which makes that easier and faster ?

Comment: Have you done any searching and reading on this topic yet? I've seen multiple related posts in the past...

Comment: Sry but they´re not so helpful for my problem
I need it specialized for Wordpress and from Postgres to MySQL

Comment: Actually it is helpful. I doubt there will be any existing tools to do Wordpress database migration from on DBMS to another. So you should take the ideas from similar posts on the "migrate from MySQL to Postgres" and apply /adjust/change them as needed.